# How to tell when を means with?

Tags: particles

I've seen the "with" use of を in the phrases (song lyrics) 未体験の怒りをごちゃまぜに (Mistranslation? "I'll mess you up with an anger you've never experienced before"), and the expression 水を満たす. Is 水を満たす merely because it's a fixed expression? Is it limited in use and how much? What tone does it give? Is 水を満たす an example of 結果の目的語 (can be interpreted as)?

Comment: How is 気になる、好きだ related to your doubt about 水を満たす?

Comment: I'm back! You can shoot a gun in both Japanese and English, b so is 未体験の怒りをごちゃまぜに mistranslated or does it use grammar that isn't in jisho that was translated the way it was?

Comment: 未体験の怒りをごちゃまぜに（して）. That を goes with する. And 光線銃を撃つ is no different in structure from the "shoot a gun" you just said.

Comment: The translator Meema did not translate it as "With my anger you've never experienced before in a jumble" but as "I'll mess you up with a anger you never exp. Before" (paraphrase)   also you didn't seem to read the comments i made below

Comment: I think you are mixing up the issue of translation and that of meaning. It is true that 水を満たす can be translated *fill something with water*, but I'd say considering it as "を means with" is off.  It is just that *fill* requires *with*-phrase and 満たす takes a direct object. Taking another example: ギャップを埋める= *fill a gap*, and it has no *with*. So the answer to your question is simply *when the English verb used in the translation requires **with***.

Comment: I'm sure I don't know what on earth am I talking about. However can you address if 未体験の怒りをごちゃ混ぜに was mistranslated (it was translated as "I'll mess you up with an anger you've never experienced before"

Comment: First note that many lyrics are not always understandable even to native speakers. It should be the case with English ones too. As it is, the phrase means *mixing up the anger of inexperience*, and what is implied is simply unclear. Translating it to *mess up with the anger of inexperience* does not make much difference. It just means 未経験の怒り is affected by the act of ごちゃまぜ.

Comment: I think there are two separate questions here that should be asked separately: one about the grammatical breakdown of 未体験の怒りをごちゃまぜに, and one about the transitivity/place structure of 満たす.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is difficult to understand.

From what I think I can understand, I believe your confusion about "を = with" comes from translating into English.

With 水を満たす, the water itself is what you are *mitasu*-ing.  There is no "with" unless you translate into English, where this could be phrased as "to fill *with* water".  But note -- when you "fill *with* water", **you are filling *something else***, and that *something else* is the direct object of the English expression.  When you 水を満たす, it is the **水** that is the direct object of the Japanese expression.

Comment: What about 未体験の怒りをごちゃまぜに and 光線銃を撃ちまくれ? I admit that my question was faulty, incomplete and hard to understand, but what about the other expressions? They're seen in 下の下 by なきそ and 千本桜 by くろうさ P.

Comment: So this comment is saying 水を満たす is a set expression and is an exception to the normal use of 満たす, as 満たす's fill meaning's use does not differ from the English fill. Ex. カップをココアで満たす = I fill a cup with cocoa (I took this usage of 満たす from jisho so there may be other usages I am missing.) To be honest, the expression would make more sense if 満たす is being interpreted as a causative form of 満つ(ちる). (See this sentence from jisho for why - バラのにおいが
部屋いっぱいに
満ちていた。
The smell of roses filled the room.— Tatoeba)

Comment: @StarPeep, for your バラ example, the バラ is the subject, as we'd expect of an intransitive verb.  To transitivize that sample sentence, バラのにおいを部屋いっぱいに満たしていた。　It might be more useful to think of the transitive 満たす as "to top up", as in "top up my coffee, please", where the "coffee" is the object.

Comment: FWIW, the 日本国語大辞典【にほんこくごだいじてん】 has this sense line for 満たす: 『いっぱいにする。あふれるまで入れる。「甕に水を満たす」』 I think that second gloss might be key: あふれるまで入れる. You're 入れる-ing the object of the verb – be it the 水 or the バラのにおい. I cannot say much about 「未体験の怒りをごちゃまぜに」 as there is no verb here, and I'm not familiar with the song.